# Looping and filtering multiple conditions on dplyr

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, filter

I haven't found a similar question, so here we are:

I have the following dataframes:

`df.filters <- data.frame(plot=c(10,10,10,15,15,20), subplot=c(1,2,3,1,2,1))`

`df.tofilter <- data.frame(plot=c(10,10,10,15,15,15,20,20,20,25,25,25,30,30,30),                                                             subplot=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),                                                variable1=c(43,45,64,54,423,754,3,534,6,346,76,345,74,23,6),                                                    variable2=c('sp1','sp2','sp3','sp4','sp5','sp3','sp3','sp3','sp4','sp6','sp1','sp2','sp5','sp5','sp2'))`

What I'm trying to do is use columns `plot` and `subplot` from `df.filters` to filter at `df.tofilter` only the respective `plot` and `subplot` rows

For example, in the above code, plot 15, even though it has subplot 1,2,3, would be filtered to only subplot 1,2. I thought about looping (for each plot, filter the subplot and the results equals the four columns (plot, subplot, variable1, variable2)) but I'm not being able to do it properly

Answer (score 1):

We may use `inner_join`

```
library(dplyr)
df.tofilter %>% 
  inner_join(df.filters)
```

Comment: Boy, that was easier than I expected...feeling dumb now. If columns have different names all I have to do besides your code is to add by = c('x' = 'y', 'a' = 'b')?

Comment: @hiperhiper if the column names are not the same for common columns, you have to add `by`